# How to add a transparent image to extend the window's border?

Tags: java, user-interface, border

I recently came across a program (*BaronReplays*) that has a transparent image on its left side of the GUI main window (check image).

Can this be done in Java and if so, what keywords do I have to search for? Google always came up with different topics when I tried to describe that customized kind of window.

In the screenshot below you can see a dragon-like image (big red box) on the left side of the main window, parts of it are transparent (small box).

[image: BaronReplays]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image is a background, not transparent. Things drawn in the content area will appear over the background. If that's what you're wanting to do, [this page](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but I think what I am looking for is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566111/can-i-place-image-outside-jframe). Basically its a transparent, undecorated child window that holds a PNG file (suports transparency). The child window's position is calculated relative to the parent frame, so it looks like the image is part of the main frame. I will try to get a working example as soon as I have more spare time.